# How to give users a user role based on their email in Python?

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm creating a registration page which contains 3 input fields: name, email, password. In my User model class, I've created a user_role method:

```
from models.base_model import BaseModel
from flask_login import UserMixin
import peewee as pw

class Users(BaseModel, UserMixin):
   name = pw.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   email = pw.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   password = pw.CharField()
   role = pw.CharField(max_length=50)

   def __init__(self, name, email, password):
       self.name = name
       self.email = email
       self.password = password

   def __repr__(self):
       return f"User: {self.name}, {self.email}, {self.role}"

   def user_roles(self):
       user_email = self.email
       self.roles = ["user","admin"]

    check_email = ["test@testing.com"]

    if user_email == check_email:
        return self.roles == "admin"
    else:
        return self.roles == "user"
```

The check_email is use to check if the email that a user fill in the field is equal to the check_email value. If it does, the role should be assign as 'admin'. In my route file, this is what it look like when saving to the database:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
     name = form.name.data
     email = form.email.data
     raw_password = form.password.data
     password = generate_password_hash(raw_password, method="sha256", salt_length=20)
     role = Users.user_roles(email)

     new_user = Users(name=name, email=email, password=password, role=role)
```

Now when I tried to test out the registration form, this is the error it gave me:

[image: Error]

I want to know is there a way to fix this error?

PS: I'm doing this for testing purposes to see if I could assign user role. I would probably add more user roles in the future, so I don't think Flask-Admin could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `user_roles` method defined as a class method when it can and should probably be a static method. Also you are calling `user_roles` with the email string but the try to access `self.email` in the method. Just change that and you are good to go.

```py
def get_role(email):
       check_email = "test@testing.com"
       if email == check_email:
           return "admin"
       else:
           return "user"
```

Edit: Forgot to remove brackets as we don't want an array but just the string.

Comment: The role is assigned as "user", not "admin" when I use the test email

Comment: @Ismail9403 Can you post some updated code in an edit?

Comment: If I'm planning to add two emails in the check_email variable, then I need to put it in a list right? Only if there's one email, then I leave it as a string

Comment: @Ismail9403 yes, just put them in an array and check `if email in check_email: ...`